Azure.Search.Documents vector search successful, but response is null
I am currently performing vector search according to the code guide that can be found here: Vector Search Using Vectorized Query
I created the index, uploaded the documents and was able to perform the search. However, the properties of the search result are always "null", even though the search was successfully performed (statusCode: 200) and the expected results can be found in Non-public members -> RawResponse -> Content: Autos
I have the impression that the response is not being correctly deserialized, even though the properties of the class I created (AzureSearchDocument) are exactly the same ones in my index: Index Information
public class AzureSearchDocument 
{ 
    public string Id { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; }     
    public string Product { get; set; }     
    public ReadOnlyMemory<float> TextEmbedding { get; set; } 
}

Here is the code that performs the search:
SearchClient searchClient = new(new Uri(_azureSearchConfig.ApiUrl), _azureSearchConfig.IndexName, new AzureKeyCredential(_keyVaultService.GetSecret(KeyVaultKeys.Azure.AISearchApiKey)));

SearchResults<AzureSearchDocument> response = await searchClient.SearchAsync<AzureSearchDocument>(
    new SearchOptions
    {
        VectorSearch = new()
        {
            Queries = { new VectorizedQuery(questionEmbedding) { KNearestNeighborsCount = maxResults, Fields = { "textEmbedding" } } }
        },
        Filter = $"product eq '{product}'"
    });

int count = 0;
await foreach (SearchResult<AzureSearchDocument> result in response.GetResultsAsync())
{
    count++;
    AzureSearchDocument doc = result.Document;
    _logger.LogInformation($"[AzureSearchDocument] {doc.Id}: {doc.Title}");
}
_logger.LogInformation($"Total number of search results:{count}");

Does anyone have any ideas I could try in order to fix this problem?
Thanks.

The issue arises because the properties of the search result are always 'null,' as the class properties must match the index fields in terms of naming and data type.
 public class AzureSearchDocument
 {
     public string Id { get; set; } = string.Empty;
     public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
     public string Product { get; set; } = string.Empty;
     public ReadOnlyMemory<float> TextEmbedding { get; set; }
 }



and vector fields are  serialization and deserialization correctly.
public static float[] SerializeVector(ReadOnlyMemory<float> vector)
{
    float[] array = new float[vector.Length];
    vector.Span.CopyTo(array);
    return array;
}

public static ReadOnlyMemory<float> DeserializeVector(float[] array)
{
    return new ReadOnlyMemory<float>(array);
}

The below code create and manage a vector search index in Azure Cognitive Search using a combination of Azure AI
        string vectorSearchProfileName = "my-vector-profile";
        string vectorSearchHnswConfig = "my-hsnw-vector-config";
        int modelDimensions = 1536;
        string indexName = configuration["SearchIndexName"] ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("SearchIndexName");

        Uri endpoint = new Uri(configuration["SearchServiceEndPoint"] ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("SearchServiceEndPoint"));
        AzureKeyCredential credential = new AzureKeyCredential(configuration["SearchServiceAdminApiKey"] ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("SearchServiceAdminApiKey"));

        SearchIndexClient indexClient = new SearchIndexClient(endpoint, credential);

        Console.WriteLine("Deleting index if exists...\n");
        await DeleteIndexIfExists(indexName, indexClient);

        Console.WriteLine("Creating index...\n");
        await CreateIndex(indexName, vectorSearchProfileName, vectorSearchHnswConfig, modelDimensions, indexClient);

        SearchClient searchClient = new SearchClient(endpoint, indexName, credential);

        Console.WriteLine("Uploading documents...\n");
        await UploadDocuments(searchClient, configuration);

        Console.WriteLine("Running vector queries...\n");
        await RunVectorQueries(searchClient, configuration);

        Console.WriteLine("Complete. Press any key to end application...\n");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task DeleteIndexIfExists(string indexName, SearchIndexClient indexClient)
    {
        try
        {
            await indexClient.GetIndexAsync(indexName);
            await indexClient.DeleteIndexAsync(indexName);
        }
        catch (RequestFailedException ex) when (ex.Status == 404)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The index doesn't exist. No deletion needed.");
        }
    }

    private static async Task CreateIndex(string indexName, string vectorSearchProfileName, string vectorSearchHnswConfig, int modelDimensions, SearchIndexClient indexClient)
    {
        var fields = new List<SearchField>
        {
            new SimpleField("Id", SearchFieldDataType.String) { IsKey = true, IsFilterable = true, IsSortable = true, IsFacetable = true },
            new SearchableField("Title") { IsFilterable = true, IsSortable = true },
            new SearchableField("Product") { IsFilterable = true, IsSortable = true, IsFacetable = true },
            new VectorSearchField("TextEmbedding", modelDimensions, vectorSearchProfileName)
        };

        var searchIndex = new SearchIndex(indexName)
        {
            Fields = fields,
            VectorSearch = new()
            {
                Profiles =
                {
                    new VectorSearchProfile(vectorSearchProfileName, vectorSearchHnswConfig)
                },
                Algorithms =
                {
                    new HnswAlgorithmConfiguration(vectorSearchHnswConfig)
                }
            }
        };

        await indexClient.CreateIndexAsync(searchIndex);
    }

    private static async Task UploadDocuments(SearchClient searchClient, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        AzureSearchDocument[] documents = GetDocuments(configuration);
        IndexDocumentsBatch<AzureSearchDocument> batch = IndexDocumentsBatch.Upload(documents);

        try
        {
            IndexDocumentsResult result = await searchClient.IndexDocumentsAsync(batch);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to index some of the documents: {ex.Message}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for documents to be indexed...\n");
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }

    private static async Task RunVectorQueries(SearchClient searchClient, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        ReadOnlyMemory<float> vectorizedResult = GetEmbeddings("Top hotels in town", configuration);

        SearchResults<AzureSearchDocument> response = await searchClient.SearchAsync<AzureSearchDocument>(
            new SearchOptions
            {
                VectorSearch = new()
                {
                    Queries = { new VectorizedQuery(vectorizedResult) { KNearestNeighborsCount = 3, Fields = { "TextEmbedding" } } }
                },
                Filter = $"Product eq 'Luxury'"
            });

        int count = 0;
        Console.WriteLine($"Single Vector Search Results:");
        await foreach (SearchResult<AzureSearchDocument> result in response.GetResultsAsync())
        {
            count++;
            AzureSearchDocument doc = result.Document;
            Console.WriteLine($"[AzureSearchDocument] {doc.Id}: {doc.Title}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Total number of search results: {count}");
    }

    public static ReadOnlyMemory<float> GetEmbeddings(string input, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Uri endpoint = new Uri(configuration["OpenAIEndPoint"] ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("OpenAIEndPoint"));
        string key = configuration["OpenAIApiKey"] ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("OpenAIApiKey");
        AzureKeyCredential credential = new AzureKeyCredential(key);

        AzureOpenAIClient openAIClient = new AzureOpenAIClient(endpoint, credential);
        EmbeddingClient embeddingClient = openAIClient.GetEmbeddingClient("text-embedding-ada-002");

        Embedding embedding = embeddingClient.GenerateEmbedding(input);
        return embedding.Vector;
    }

    public static AzureSearchDocument[] GetDocuments(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new AzureSearchDocument
            {
                Id = "1",
                Title = "Fancy Stay",
                Product = "Luxury",
                TextEmbedding = GetEmbeddings(
                    "Best hotel in town if you like luxury hotels. They have an amazing infinity pool, a spa, " +
                    "and a really helpful concierge. The location is perfect -- right downtown, close to all " +
                    "the tourist attractions. We highly recommend this hotel.",
                    configuration)
            },
            new AzureSearchDocument
            {
                Id = "2",
                Title = "Roach Motel",
                Product = "Budget",
                TextEmbedding = GetEmbeddings("Cheapest hotel in town. In fact, a motel.", configuration)
            },
            // Add more documents here...
        };
    }
}

public class AzureSearchDocument
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Product { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public ReadOnlyMemory<float> TextEmbedding { get; set; }
}



I'm sorry, but you just copied the documentation that I have already been through. It didn't help solve my problem.

@Ross In your index, set the search item to true for your fields of title, ID, and product, and set textEmbedding to retriable. Then, run the indexer again.

I did it, still getting nulls everywhere, except for the Non-public members, which I am not able to retrieve using the GetResultsAsync() method.

@Ross Could you please share the indexes and search explorer results in text format mentioned in the above question?
